# Modify colnames in R composed of string and number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big df with colnames like this:

```
dput(head(colnames(count)[c(2,3,4,7,8)]))
c("A001", "A002", "A004", "A008", "A009")
```

I want to substract the number part and keep the letter, which is not a constant string and in other columns it will be B, C etc.
result should look like this:

c("A000", "A001", "A003", "A007", "A008")

So far I was trying this which deals with the number -1 but it doesn't keep the letter.

```
as.numeric(str_extract(colnames(count), "[0-9]+"))-1
c("0", "1", "3", "7", "8")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to extract the numbers and letter and operate on them, then `sprintf` to format your string:

```r
vec <- c("A001", "A002", "B004", "A008", "D009")

sprintf("%s%03d", gsub("\\d", "", vec), as.integer(gsub('\\D', "", vec)) - 1)
# [1] "A000" "A001" "B003" "A007" "D008"
```

Comment: Almost what i want but doesnt deal with the B,C etc

Answer (score 4):

One base R option:

```
x = c("A001", "A002", "B004", "C008", "D009")
sapply(
  strsplit(x, "(?<=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE),
  \(x) sprintf("%s%03d", x[1], as.numeric(x[2])-1)
)
# [1] "A000" "A001" "B003" "C007" "D008"
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I implemented it like this and it also works
```
sapply(
    strsplit(colnames(count), "(?<=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE),
    \(x) sprintf("%s%03d",x[1], as.numeric(x[2])-1)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `str_replace` which can take a function as well

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(vec, "\\d+", function(x) sprintf('%03d', as.numeric(x) - 1))
[1] "A000" "A001" "B003" "A007" "D008"
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("A001", "A002", "B004", "A008", "D009")
```